# Is exchange of numbers in Dirichlet characters possible?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, characters

The following is from page 139 of the book Apostol's Analytic Number Theory calculating Dirichlet characters mod 5 and 7:

[image]

My question is that can any of the rows inside the red squares be exchanged with another one, with $\chi_i$'s fixed? (for example what are written for $\chi_3$ can be written for $\chi_4$ and simultaneously vice versa.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are really asking about whether Apostol is using some sort of cannonical labeling for the Dirichlet characters, so that the label $\chi_2$ has some semantic meaning in itself.

But in Apostol's book, there is nothing special about the subscripts. So the character $\chi_2$ could just as easily have been called $\chi_3$, and vice versa. The principal character $\chi_1$ is special. And in these tables it's clear that $\chi_2$ is special in the sense that it's "simpler" than the others. But that's it.

Comment: My question is can we choose the (ordered) ${\{1, -i, i, -1,0}\}$ for $\chi_3$ and ${\{1, i, -i, -1,0}\}$ for $\chi_4$? Also, what it means "it's "simpler" than the others"? ; appearance of 1 and -1's perhaps you mean? Thanks.

Comment: Yes --- the labels are meaningless.